# Advice to correct and improve a network diagram

Tags: network, architecture

I need to build a "secure"-network diagram with Visio for my school.
I already build it but I want to get some advise about it to tell me if I made some big mistake or if I can improve it. My diagram is a simplified view of a university network.

[image]

Thanks for your help :)
have a nice day !

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way we can tell if your diagram is accurate or not.  So we can't help you on that point.

You should consider what the purpose of your diagram is, and that will help you include the right information on it.

For example, you can make it a physical diagram, showing how devices are physically connected to each other. You should include port numbers, bandwidth, etc.  This would be used for low level troubleshooting.

You can create a logical topology, which shows the IP addressing and subnets from a layer 3 perpective.

You can also create a data flow diagram, which shows the components and data flows from an application perspective.  This will show how various applications rely on specific components.

Ultimately, there is no right or wrong way, as long as the diagram provides the information the reader needs.